# My second monitor doesn't work

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, nvidia-graphics-card

I am trying to run two monitors:

1. My primary monitor is a RCA 24" monitor, running on HDMI,
   and everything is working fine on it.
2. My second monitor is a ViewSonic 20", on DVI.

The problem is that my second monitor is not working. All the cables are plugged in, and when I go to my settings it says a second monitor is detected. However when I turn it on, it shows a message saying "No Signal Digital".

I am also currently running the NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 and I'm wondering if this could have something to do with it.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: No **digital** signal means that the monitor is not receiving a signal on is digital inputs.   If the monitor has two inputs (e.g. ancient VGA and DVI) then it is likely configured to show the signal from the analog plug. Which you can change via the on screen display.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the hardware part is all ok (monitors, cables etc.) then most probably **you need to extend your desktop onto 2nd monitor.**

Depending on your OS there are different ways to achieve this.

See [here](https://www.repeatsoftware.com/help/MultipleMonitors.htm), [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-up-multiple-monitors-with-windows-7.html) or [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/can-i-add-a-second-monitor-to-my-pc.html) (perhaps the best) for different explanations about how to do this for different versions of Windows.

Comment: Also, make sure the graphics card is giving the second monitor a suitable resolution for what the monitor can handle :) quite often a too high resolution can result in "no input/signal"